# How can I recover files from a Fusion Drive if the iMac no longer works using an M1 Mac?

Tags: macos, data-recovery, fusion-drive

I have an iMac with a broken motherboard. I got the HDD out of it and I now want to view my files on my Mac M1 device.

It shows my external device on Disk utility, but I'm unable to view the device through finder?

I know the old device is an HFS+ and my new Mac M1 is AFPS.
It was a fusion disk, like I said, I can't use the motherboard any more.

The tool/cable etc to read the HDD works.

This is what I see in Disk utility
[image]

[image]

[image]

Not sure if it was encrypted.
Disk Drill can scan the documents, so there must be a way that I can view them through other ways that don't require me to pay 300$.

I was also able to remove the PCIe SSD from the iMac and figuring out how to connect this to my Mac M1 via USB.
If I where to attach them both to my MacOs would read them as a fusion drive through help of a software?

Comment: Which iMac model is the disk from? Was it encrypted? How is the disk recognized in Disk Utility (screenshot)?

Comment: Did the iMac also have an SSD in there… a fusion drive? If so, you need both to be able to read it. they will not operate independently. The new Mac is, of course, perfectly capable of reading HFS+ if nothing else is preventing it.

Comment: Thanks for the super edits @nohillside - always appreciated

Comment: @Tetsujin any idea if I can remove the SSD and hook it op to a SATA cable to USB and read it together through my new Mac?

Comment: The Fusion drive can be rebuilt - see https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT207584 and https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/261154/how-do-i-re-fuse-an-unfused-fusion-drive-ideally-without-formatting?rq=1 Both of these assume the drives are still in the original iMac, so you may have to modify the procedure [e.g. you may not have to be in Recovery to do it]. It's not something I've ever done personally, so idk the details.

Comment: Your latest edit changes the question from "how to access HFS+ from M1" to "How to rebuild a Fusion drive on a different Mac". This is totally fine, but please edit the whole question (including the subject line) to make this more easy to understand.